# How to obtain yahoo finance ticker data for stocks that are no longer listed (etc. merge, bankruptcy, etc.)?

Tags: programming, yahoofinance

I am trying to use the Python library `yfinance` to obtain stock data for some companies on a list provided to me (just a fairly generic list). However, amongst this list are companies which are no longer listed on the exchanges for a variety of reasons (e.g. bankruptcy, merged, etc.).

**Question**: How can I obtain the stock price data for these companies during an earlier time period? One earlier post () suggests that I would need to pay to get the data for securities which are no longer listed - is this still true?

Some examples are:

- Lehman Brothers (the former bank)
- Yahoo
- United Technologies (merged with Raytheon)
- and a few others

**Attempt**:
My current use of the module uses the following code (for use within a Google Colab environment):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# pip install yfinance
!pip install yfinance

import yfinance as yf

start_date_string = "2006-01-01" # some made up dates
end_date_string = "2006-12-31" 

d = yf.download("[insert string of the ticker]", start=start_date_string, end=end_date_string)
```

However, the tickers for some of these companies don't work so I don't know how to get that data.

Comment: Delisted stock data is not provided by Yahoo.  Well researched/curated data sets typically cost money.  If you are a student at a University, ask your Finance Department - they might be able to help you.  Otherwise, you can look for paid sources of such data.  Disclosure:  I am a director/co-owner of Norgate Data that provides such data.

Comment: @NorgateData - okay many thanks for the confirmation! I shall keep those points in mind.